# Files already existing at the unload destination: s3://snowflake. Use overwrite option to force unloading. - Java, SpringBoot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using SpringBoot and Java to copy data from tables in `Snowflake` to `S3 bucket`.

I am using this code:

```
"COPY INTO s3://snowflake/"+ userId +" from \"TEST\".\"PUBLIC\".\"USER_TABLE_TEMP\" storage_integration = s3_int file_format = CSV_TEST;";
```

And it works. I am puting userId as prefix to file.

What it doesn't work is when I try to copy data for the same user, for a user that `.csv` file already exists on bucket.

When I try to do it, I am getting this error:

```
Files already existing at the unload destination: s3://snowflake/1. Use overwrite option to force unloading.
```

How can I make this work so that the new file overwrites the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the OVERWRITE-parameter and put it to true within the COPY-command.

Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#copy-options-copyoptions

So the statement is..

```
COPY INTO ...
file_format = CSV_TEST
OVERWRITE=TRUE;
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.